# What's the biggest circle that can fit between 2 Gaussian curves?

Tags: calculus

What's the biggest radius possible for a circle to fit completely between the curve $y = e^{-x^2}$ and $y = -e^{-x^2}$ ?

This isn't homework, I was just thinking about this randomly. I know calculus will be involved to find the radius, but I just can't figure out how to proceed. r=1 is too big

Answer (score 29):

The circle by the points $(\pm x,\pm e^{-x^2})$ and centered at the origin has the squared radius

$$r^2=x^2+e^{-2x^2},$$

which, by differentiation, achieves the minimum

$$r^2_{min}=\frac{\ln 2+1}2.$$

[image]

---

**Addendum:**

Let us consider the *offset curve* at distance $2r_{min}$ (as if the circle was rolling on it). From the parametric equations

$$\begin{cases}x=t,\\y=e^{-t^2},\end{cases}$$

we draw the green curve below

$$\begin{cases}x'=x-\frac{2r_{min}2te^{-t^2}}{\sqrt{1+4t^2e^{-2t^2}}},\\
y'=y-\frac{2r_{min}}{\sqrt{1+4t^2e^{-2t^2}}}.\end{cases}$$

[image]

The portion of the curve between the two cusps$^*$ mustn't be considered, because it corresponds to a section where the radius of curvature is smaller than $r_{min}$ so that the circle is *externally* tangent.

This shows that no larger circle can be tangent to the upper curve without passing the lower one and validates the intuitive choice of the center at the origin.

$^*$ The cusps are at the same time the tangency points of the circle to the lower curve.

Comment: Can you use calculus of variation here?

Comment: @ArtificialStupidity: I don't know, sounds overkill.

Comment: You have used same approach as theo and also without justifying why origin is taken as centre if circle. I am not complaining btw!

Comment: @samjoe: I have added some material about global maximality. The argument tries to show that $r_{min}$ can't be exceeded. This settles the "center at origin" issue.

Answer (score 15):

It seems geometrically obvious to me that the centre for such a circle must be the origin. Thus, we are trying to find the closest point from the origin to the two curves. The curves can be parameterised by $(x, \pm e^{-x^2})$, which yields a parameterised square distance,
$$f(x) = x^2 + e^{-2x^2}$$
Differentiating,
$$f'(x) = 2x - 4xe^{-2x^2}.$$
This comes to $0$ when $x = 0$ or $e^{-2x^2} = 1/2$, that is, when $x = \pm \sqrt{\log(2)} / \sqrt{2}$. Clearly, as $x \to \pm\infty$, the distance approaches infinity. So, the minimum must occur at one of our critical points. Checking, we get,
\begin{align*}
f(0) &= 1 \\
f\left(\pm \frac{\sqrt{\log(2)}}{\sqrt{2}}\right) &= \frac{\log(2)}{2} + e^{-2\frac{\log(2)}{2}} = \frac{\log(2) + 1}{2} < 1.
\end{align*}
Thus, the radius of the largest inscribed circle is
$$\sqrt{\frac{\log(2) + 1}{2}}.$$

EDIT: Since none of the answers are dealing with it, and certain doubts have been expressed, I thought I'd deal with the centre having to be $(0, 0)$.

Essentially, the property needed here is [orthogonal convexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_convex_hull) of the region bounded by the two curves. Note that a region bounded by any two graphs of functions is always vertically convex, by the nature of functions; a failure to be vertically convex would violate the vertical line test.

For horizontal convexity, take two points $(x_1, y), (x_2, y)$ in the region. If $y = 0$, then clearly $\lambda(x_1, y) + (1 - \lambda)(x_2, y)$ lies on the $x$-axis and hence is in the region, so assume $y \neq 0$. By symmetry, without loss of generality, we may assume $y > 0$, thus we only need worry about the curve $y = e^{-x^2}$.

Since $(x_1, y), (x_2, y)$ are in the region, but above the $x$-axis, it follows that $y < e^{-x_1^2}$ and $y < e^{-x_2^2}$. Since $e^{-x^2}$ is decreasing for $x \ge 0$ and increasing for $x \le 0$, it follows by cases that
$$y < \min \left\lbrace e^{-x_1^2}, e^{-x_2^2}\right\rbrace \le e^{-(\lambda x_1 + (1 - \lambda)x_2)^2}$$
for $\lambda \in [0, 1]$. Thus, we have orthogonal convexity.

How does this help us? Suppose we have another point $(x, y)$ centering a largest inscribed circle in the region. If $y \neq 0$, then $(x, -y)$ does as well, by symmetry. By vertical convexity, $(x, 0)$ will do the same; just picture the vertical convex hull of the two balls and realise it contains the same circle centred at $(x, 0)$. Similarly, by horizontal convexity, $(0, 0)$ will host a largest inscribed circle.

As I said in the comments, this can be proven a bit more thoroughly, but this is the geometric intuition here.

Comment: "It seems geometrically obvious to me that the centre for such a circle must be the origin". Why?

Comment: Well, it is not always true that an object maximizing something must come from symmetry considerations. If this is true, it should be justified.

Comment: I mean, maybe it is true in this case but I do not see it. Why a circle with maximal radius between two gaussians must be symmetrical with respect to the y-axis?

Comment: @FrancescoPolizzi This can be more rigorously justified, but it seems obvious to me due to the monotone decreasing nature of the curves as $|x|$ increases, that you will always be able to inscribe a larger circle when you decrease $|x|$. Also, if this maximal circle doesn't centre on the $x$-axis, then one can find another maximal circle reflected by the $x$-axis. Think about what this would mean if the midpoint of these two points were not also a maximal circle - it would mean that the curves would have to double back on themselves, causing them not to be the graphs of functions.

Comment: Thank you for answering. Based on these comments here, I was wondering what to do to find the center for a circle if it's not obvious. For example, between the curves $x^2 = 4y + 4$ and $y = e^{-x^2}$? (Sorry if the example's calculations are too tedious, I just wanted an example)

Comment: @Rick: Symmetry is your friend in these situations. If you can narrow down the centre of the circle by some kind of geometric reasoning, it always helps. You could otherwise try a naive approach, where you consider a point in the region and compute its infimal distance to the two curves. You can then figure out where this distance is maximised.

Comment: @Rick - in the most general situation, you can define $d(x,y, t)$ to be the distance (or distance squared, which is usually easier) from $(x,y)$ to $\gamma(t)$ - a parametrization of your curves. For fixed $x,y$, minimize this over $t$ to get $d_1(x,y)$, the distance from $(x,y)$ to the nearest point on the curves., then minimize that over all $x,y$ to find the center and radius of your circle. This can be a lot of work, but if you have good formulas for your curves, it is generally possible. Much better to take advantage of symmetry when it is available, though.